# Trailing spaces cant be removed in WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, trim

I need to list out the records with some records in column_A & column_B both are of char(10) type. But the issue is Column_A has **trailing spaces** in it, Even though  both the columns having same data but it couldn't match.

I tried to **LTRIM**(**RTRIM**(column_A)), **REPLACE**(column_A, **CHAR(32)**, '') etc., but none of them doesn't work. 
Could someone suggest any other method to solve this issue.

**Note**: The above mentioned methods are resulting fine in **SELECT** clause.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: SQL Server often ignores trailing spaces when doing comparisons.  Can you provide an example of what isn't working?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a trailing space and not another unseen character?

Comment: What does `ASCII(RIGHT(column_A,1))` return? If it's not `32`, that isn't a trailing space you have there.

Comment: Yes Larnu, I had verified it by CAST(column_A AS VARBINARY(MAX)) resulting 2020 if it hasing 2 spaces at the end

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(COLA)) = LTRIM(RTRIM(COLB))
```

Comment: . . .  `RTRIM` is not necessary for `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @YogeshSharma The OP mentions *trailing spaces* so LTRIM is also not needed, so `WHERE COLA = COLB` would work, but it does not.

Comment: What you had said was my first try to filter the data, but it was not working as it should. For further conformation i had verified what are the characters at the end of the string/data it was couple of spaces. eg- 'ABCD   '